# Order of child blocks in HTML_Template_IT - does it matter?

Tags: php, html, templates, block, pear

I am working on simple php based survey generator. All it does is gets questionnaire from DB and creates appropriate form on the page. For templating I'm using PEAR HTML_Template_IT (1.3) and I have stumbled upon an interesting 'feature'.

Let's assume we have template with nesting structure like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN questionnaire -->

  <!-- BEGIN question.T -->
  {question} <input type="text" .... />
  <!-- END question.T -->

  <!-- BEGIN question.R -->
  {question}

    <!-- BEGIN question.R.answer -->
    <input type="radio" .... /> {option}
    <!-- END question.R.answer -->

  <!-- END question.R -->

<!-- END questionnaire -->
```

As you can immagine I have similar blocks for different types of input fields.

Now here comes interesting thing. When I try to display fields I have noticed they are being displayed in a weird way. First I will have text blocks, and at the end all questions with radio group. When I force my code to only use question.T (for example) to display questions then the order is just fine, but when I get to Radio,Select,Checkbox blocks (which all have inner 'answer' blocks) ordering seems to be no longer there. So my assumption would be it's something to do with the template structure. Funny thing is, when I swap blocks order in template ("question.R" being first) the result is that all 'Radio' questions are being displayed first then text fields. So it seems like the order in the template child blocks somehow matters but don't know why.

Has anyone stumbled upon such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `parse()` an inner block like `question.T` or `question.R` and then parse an outer `questionnaire` block.

If you rewrite this template as PHP instead of IT syntax it will look like this

```
foreach ($questionnaire as $q) {
    if ('text' == $q['type']) {
        // output text field
    } elseif ('radio' == $q['type'] {
        // output radio buttons
    }
}
```

So basically you have to drive the `foreach` loop. Look how e.g. ITDynamic renderer in [HTML_QuickForm package](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm) works when outputting the form.